# C# - Local and staging environments detect different database structure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2012

I have an app that I develop locally, and a version of the app on a staging environment. They both share the same database hosted on another remote server.

Earlier today, the remote server hosting the database went down for unknown reasons. It is now back up and running, however changes I made to it over the last few weeks were gone.

I managed to recreate my changes, possible some tables are using a different name (ie. RequestLog instead of RequestsLog).

After making necessary changes on my local version app, and recompiling it, it works. However, when I then publish and deploy to my staging server, it seems to be referencing the old database structure.

For starters, it says that Stored Procedure x does not exist, even though I can clearly see in the database that it exists. Another existing table is still missing a field according to the staging environment, but on my local environment the field exists.

Both versions use the same database, and use the same log in and passwords. There are no permission issues, since the owner is set to be the current owner of that database.

Things I have tried:

- Restarting the application on IIS on the staging server
- Recycling the application pool on IIS on the staging server
- Doing a clean and build on the solution, before publishing (about 5 times)
- Full re-deployment
- Taking the database offline, and switching it back online
- Replacing bins on staging with the locally produced bins for IIS Express

Can anyone offer an idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: Let me ask the right question here: Why does it come you loose 2  weeks of database changes when a server goes down and to a backup? Taking backups is baseline for any developer. I take backups of all systems 2x per day, critical all 15 minutes.

Comment: Hi, I looked through the database back up plans to find a copy of the database backup to restore, however I found that it was dated 6 months ago. This leads me to believe that the hosting company did not do a reboot, but rather an image restoration dated to 6 months ago.

Comment: Which is all your fault. Seriously. You should take backups for the database outside what they do automatically. And take it a LOT more often - multiple times per day.

Comment: Hi, I admit the fault is because for some reason, whoever set up the maintenance plans had the files written to an on-site disk, rather than off-site. The database backup plan is tested to be working, however there was a huge timestamp gap between 6 months ago and now that was missing.

However, my question here is to solve the issue as listed above. Please don't change the topic.

Comment: As you may realize - I am not changing the topic. Merely commenting. Sadly you likely are out of answers here - beccause there is nothing you can do. Likely the database you ahave is simply corrupt. Have you run an integrity check?

Comment: I restored a live version of the database on to a staging environment, and re-applied my changes. The site itself works fine when I host both the site and the database on different servers than where they were originally hosted from, using the exact same settings everywhere else. However, if I put them both back into their original environments, I get the same errors again. I am beginning to suspect it's more of an environment issue.